# A reputation for something

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, simplified-characters

I know the word for reputation is 声誉, but how would I use this word to form sentences like:

> Chinese has a reputation **for** being a hard language.
>
> This boy has a reputation **for** being naughty.

What would 'for' be? How do I form this structure?

Thanks.

Comment: LINE dict, Examples (have rep. for [some quality]):因…而闻名,因...而名声在外,有...的名声, have a reputation for being + adjective: replace ... by the adjective, find many more samples both at LINE dict. and jukuu,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

《牛津現代英漢雙解詞典》 shows an example, "have a reputation for laziness/for being lazy 以懶惰出名".

Chinese has a reputation for being a hard language.
中文以困難而出名。

This boy has a reputation for being naughty.
這男孩以淘氣而出名。

for 以